# get javascript code from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am loading external javascript code to iframe with

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://external.tld/code"></iframe>
```

output from "external.tld/code" is:

```
var myvar="";
function something(){}
```

now I need to get this code as a plaintext to javascript variable in my main window. How? 
I tried document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML but is is not working.

Comment: you can't do that as javascript, thankfully, does not allow such cross origin shenanigans

Comment: @JaromandaX — Well, you can, so long as external.tld co-operates.

Comment: @Quentin - then it's not a shenanigan :p

Comment: and how please? I just need to get html code in plaintext, so myvar should be just html text and not javascript code anymore. (or maybe to use another way and not iframe)